# How to select the appropriate package for my Linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

As I wanted to install [Cloudera Hadoop](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation#CDH3Installation-Step2), and I got the following message:

> Click this link for your Red Hat/CentOS 5 system, or on this other
>   link for your Red Hat 6 system, choose Save File, and save it to a
>   directory to which you have write access (it can be your home
>   directory).

It says for Red Hat/CentOS 5 system and for Red Hat 6 system use this file, but which one is for me, as I am using Ubuntu 8.04?

Comment: Look closer on that URL: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation#CDH3Installation-InstallingCDH3onUbuntuSystems

Comment: which will be of 8.04 squeeze or lenny ?

Comment: Neither. Have you even looked at Ubuntu's website? The answer is right there.

Comment: I had searched http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system) but it doesn't say about squeeze an lenny , so found squeeze is of version 6.0 in this link http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads , so i think i should use squeeze what uh say ?

Comment: centos/redhat packages will come in .rpm files, and debian/ubuntu ones in .deb files. .tar.gz is equivilent to a zip file and usualy contains the source code to be compiled from scratch - which is best avoided if you can get a rpm or deb file.

Comment: 8.04 is Hardy Heron. I found this by typing "Ubuntu 8.04" in Google and clicking on the first link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/8.04/. squeeze and lenny are **Debian** releases. Ubuntu is based on Debian, but you're a little confused, I think.